# very fast PUT requests result in ECONNRESET

Tags: request, pouchdb, hapi.js

I am trying to create a server to receive PUT requests from remote clients (sensors)… all this is baby-steps for me. I have a simple `hapijs` server listening on port 3000 and inserting data into a PouchDB database. When I send a few (5 or so) PUT requests using the `nodejs` `request` package, the records are entered fine. But if I want to test with a large amount (500 PUT requests), I get

```
○ → node bin/new_records.js --num 500
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNRESET 127.0.0.1:3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1036:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1059:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
```

How do I get past this? Ideally the server should be able to handle as many PUT requests as fast as possible (even though in real life the situation may be a lot more tranquil).

Comment: What version of node is this?

Comment: nodejs version 6.6.0

Comment: I can't see the source for that version, there is some unhandled error within code leading to this error.  I suggest you post a snippet of code demonstrating your issue.